# 3rd party DLL crashes with System.AccessViolationException (Protected Memory)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nullreferenceexception

I'm using C# in .Net 4.0 and VS2010 and I'm using a few unmanaged 3rd party DLLs (from the same vendors).  The DLLs process an array of bytes from a file, execute their logic, and return something new.  This works with about 80% of files, but the rest crash the application.  This is reproducible with the same files.  The exception is:

System.AccessViolationException
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

It crashes on this line:

```
oPages = _penReq.Pages;
```

This does not happen with an older version of software (from about 2008) calling the same DLLs and processing the same files.  I've added this to the configuration file:

```
<legacyNullReferenceExceptionPolicy enabled = "1"/>
```

With this added, the program doesn't crash (there is a try-catch around the problem line) but of course oPages is then null.

I realize this is a 3rd party unmanaged DLL so there is only so much help I can get without contacting this vendor (which is very difficult), but considering this same code and DLLs work with an older version of our software, is there an explanation or possible solution?

To make this somewhat more interesting, about 25% of the files that crash on our Server 2003 32bit machine are successfully processed on my Win7 64bit machine.

Thanks.

**Update**

Here is a better look at the code:

```
byte[] inkBytes = Data;   //produces an array of Bytes
Vendor.Service.PenRequest _penReq = new Vendor.Service.PenRequest();
_penReq.Initialize(Data);
_penId = _penReq.PenId;  //returns a string with an ID.  Confirmed working.
Vendor.Service.RequestPages oPages = _penReq.Pages; //returns list of pages.  Not working
```

Comment: Are they providing a managed wrapper, or are you PInvoking it yourself?

Comment: Is `oPages = _penReq.Pages` code that you write to access the DLLs' output? Is it code within the DLLs themselves?

Comment: I have this a lot when working in virtualized environments, are you using any virtual host to run these machines?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know what that means.  I'm just calling the DLLs like "private dllvar foo;"  I was originally just calling it from a windows service but since I've gotten this error I've been wrapping them in a separate .exe console application and calling it from there to test.  I pass the byte array as an argument.

Comment: Jonathan both _penReq and oPages are variables I've called within my code that are from the DLLs.  Trikks I'm running this from my Bootcamp partition using parallels, but it happens when just booting my Windows Partition and when using the Server 2003 machine.

Comment: You've right clicked the DLL's and made sure 'Unblock' was clicked, correct?

Comment: @Josh I've right clicked on them but there is no unblock option.  I've googled the option you are talking about and I definitely don't see it.

Comment: Post some code.  It sounds like the call convention do not match.

Comment: @Ramhound I've posted updated code.  Let me know if it is enough.  The code in this method is very small so there isn't much else to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new security feature in Dot Net 2.0 over 1.1 that requires you to have full trust over unmanaged files and resources before you can use them. Make sure that the dlls and any resources that it uses must have got full access as well as they are fully trusted.

Comment: The application has full trust but it still crashes on specific files.

Comment: Not the application itself. I mean any resource that the 3rd party dll is trying to access.

Comment: I added them to the GAC using gacutil.exe, does that not give them full trust?

Comment: In your application, set the 3rd party dlls as well as any resources you are using to Copy Local = true